# Google Cloud Service Account with 'roles/container.admin'

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create a Service Account with 'roles/container.admin' and i get an error saying that the role is not supported for this resource.

```
$ gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding sa-ci-vm@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member='serviceAccount:sa-ci-vm@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/container.admin'

ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/container.admin is not supported for this resource.
```

If I create a Service Account from the CONSOLE UI I can add this role without a problem.

Answer (score 17):

You have to use `gcloud projects` to add roles for a service account at a project level as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource).

This works for me:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \ 
--member serviceAccount:sa-ci-vm@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/container.admin
```

Comment: This would have been a useful comment within the documentation :)

Comment: For those using Terraform, the equivalent Terraform resource is `google_project_iam_binding` https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_binding

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error. You have to give the absolute path to the role.

cloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding  **SERVICEACCOUNT** --member=**SERVICEACCOUNT_EMAIL** --role=projects/**PROJECTNAME**/roles/**ROLENAME**

Answer (score 0):

as Vinayak pointed out you need to refer to the role with its ID which includes `projects/$project_id`. I ran into this in Terraform, so if you are creating the roles as well as the binding in Terraform make sure to reference the custom role like this:

```hcl
resource "google_project_iam_member" "binding" {
    project = var.project_id
    role    = google_project_iam_custom_role.custom_role.id
    member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "custom_role" {
    project = var.project_id
    role_id = "CustomRole"
    title   = "custom role"
    permissions = [
        "pubsub.snapshots.create",
        "pubsub.snapshots.delete",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: That is a solution to a different problem related to custom roles id. Original question was about a built-in role and had resource/account swapped.